# Exception trying to @Autowire a @Component

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I get a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when I try to autowire a component

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.github.robertobatts.restapi.repository.OrderRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

This is the code where I try to autowire:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/order", produces = "application/json")
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository repository;

...

}
```

and this is the component:

```
@Component
public class OrderRepository extends InMemoryRepository<Order> {

    @Override
    protected void updateIfExists(Order original, Order updated) {
        original.setDescription(updated.getDescription());
        original.setCostInCents(updated.getCostInCents());
        original.setComplete(updated.isComplete());
    }

}
```

All the objects used by OrderRepository are standard java objects with no spring annotations.

Here is the structure of the packages:

```
restapi
    SpringBootApplication.java
    controller
        OrderController.java
    repository
        OrderRepository.java
```

Comment: What is the package of OrderController? And please show the main application code.

Comment: Probably you haven’t configured packages to scan and your package layout does not conform to standard  spring boot layout, and thus your bean is not discovered.

Comment: If your application is not in the root of the package you will have to specify the folder where the components should be scanned. Could you provide your tree structure of the project?

Comment: I edited the post adding the package structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please move your `@SpringBootApplication` [annotated class](https://github.com/robertobatts/rest-api-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/robertobatts/restapi/main/RestApiExampleApplication.java) one package level up.

The annotation itself contains `@ComponentScan` and ...

> If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the package of the class that declares this annotation.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

---

These changes on `34ced93` gave me the expected stdout line using `mvn clean spring-boot:run`.

```
diff --git a/src/main/java/com/github/robertobatts/restapi/main/RestApiExampleApplication.java b/src/main/java/com/github/robertobatts/restapi/RestApiExampleApplication.java
similarity index 86%
rename from src/main/java/com/github/robertobatts/restapi/main/RestApiExampleApplication.java
rename to src/main/java/com/github/robertobatts/restapi/RestApiExampleApplication.java
index bc01db5..affb928 100644
--- a/src/main/java/com/github/robertobatts/restapi/main/RestApiExampleApplication.java
+++ b/src/main/java/com/github/robertobatts/restapi/RestApiExampleApplication.java
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-package com.github.robertobatts.restapi.main;
+package com.github.robertobatts.restapi;

 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
diff --git a/src/main/java/com/github/robertobatts/restapi/repository/OrderRepository.java b/src/main/java/com/github/robertobatts/restapi/repository/OrderRepository.java
index b356e74..554610a 100644
--- a/src/main/java/com/github/robertobatts/restapi/repository/OrderRepository.java
+++ b/src/main/java/com/github/robertobatts/restapi/repository/OrderRepository.java
@@ -1,4 +1,6 @@
 package com.github.robertobatts.restapi.repository;

+import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
+
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@@ -8,4 +10,9 @@ import com.github.robertobatts.restapi.domain.Order;
 public class OrderRepository extends InMemoryRepository<Order> {

+       @PostConstruct
+       private void test() {
+               System.out.println("OrderRepository ready.");
+       }
+
        @Override
        protected void updateIfExists(Order original, Order updated) {
```

Comment: Look at my package structure. SpringBootApplication is already on level up from the othere packages but still doesn't work

Comment: @robertobatts Please move `RestApiExampleApplication` from `com.github.robertobatts.restapi.main` to `com.github.robertobatts.restapi`

Comment: It's already there. I posted the github code before but I forgot to commit this. It doesn't work anyway

Comment: @robertobatts Did you refactor the package name in the Java file also? I will have a try by myself.

Comment: @robertobatts I added my working diff. Please have a try. I would also recommend to use the latest release version instead of a build snapshot, but that probably won't be the problem here.